# Laravel 4: named routes in named groups

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to make something like this?

```
Route::group(array('as' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'admin'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index'));
    Route::get('users', array('as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'AdminController@users'));
});
```

The goal is to do not include "admin" in all names and make links for above example like this:

```
URL::route('admin.home');
URL::route('admin.users');
```

Above example doesn't work:

```
Illegal offset type in unset
laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php:5053
```

Named group with nonamed routes inside works.
Named routes in nonamed group work too.
But not together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'adminAuth'], function(){
    // If you do not want to repeat 'admin' in all route names, 
    // define the value here
    $r = 'admin';

    Route::get('users', ['as' => "{$r}.users", 'uses' => 'AdminController@users']);
    Route::get('/', ['as' => "{$r}.root", 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
});
```

In yout views/redirect you can use `URL::action('ControllerName@method)` and Laravel will know where redirect/point to...

Comment: but you are using a "prefix->admin" in the route group - I dont think you need to reattach the prefix to each individual route?

Comment: Prefix serves for catching URL, so that you do not need to write 'admin/users' inside the group, 'users' portion of URL is enough. It has nothing to do with route names

Comment: arh - ok - that makes sense

Comment: Thank you. Using a var may be a workaround. Sad, that name nesting doesn't work =(

Comment: Would be great, if 'prefix' and other params could be passed into the closure. That way, there is no need to define prefix inside the closure body. Maybe we could fill a request for Taylor?!